# How do put the JSON into EXTJS Grid?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, combobox, grid

I have a search with 3 Comboboxes if they are selected, the selected valueid send them by $POST and then by AJAX to PHP.

PHP is building from the combobox id's a mysql query and sends it back as JSON. 
(JSON is validated)

But my grid is not filled! how i put the filtered by id data in my grid?

My Button

```
buttons:[
            {
                text:'Search',
                loadingText:'lädt',
                handler:function () {
                    var form = Ext.getCmp('searchPanel').getForm();
                    form.submit(
                        {url: 'php/search.php'}

               )
```

MY validated JSON

```
"getRoutedata": [
    {
        "RouteID": "3",
        "Loadingpoint": "Hafencity",
        "Postalcode": "20457",
        "Containercity": "Uhlenhorst",
        "Carrier": "Bre SO",
        "Transportmodel": "Truck",
        "Containersize": "40",
        "Containertype": "Horizontal",
        "Harbor": "Antwerpen",
        "Price": "1000.00",
        "Year": "2012",
        "Misc": "test"
    }
]
```

My Store

```
    storePPT = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url:'php/search.php',
    storeId:'myStore',
    root:'getRoutedata',
    stateful:true,
    idProperty:'RouteID',
    fields:[
        {name:'Carrier', type:'string', mapping:'Carrier'},
        {name:'Containercity', type:'string', mapping:'Containercity'},
        {name:'Containersize', type:'string', mapping:'Containersize'},
        {name:'Containertype', type:'string', mapping:'Containertype'},
        {name:'Harbor', type:'string', mapping:'Harbor'},
        {name:'Loadingpoint', type:'string', mapping:'Loadingpoint'},
        {name:'Misc', type:'string', mapping:'Misc'},
        {name:'Postalcode', type:'string', mapping:'Postalcode'},
        {name:'Price', type:'decimal', mapping:'Price'},
        {name:'Transportmodel', type:'string', mapping:'Transportmodel'},
        {name:'Year', type:'year', mapping:'Year'},
        {name:'RouteID', type:'int', mapping:'RouteID'}
    ]
});
```

Big thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have store that will hold parsed data from your JSON response and a grid that will display data from this store. like:

```
//call this function in ajax success
function loadJsonData() {
   var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JSONStore', {
                 fields: [
                         {name1: 'field_name1'},
                         {name2: 'field_name2'},
                         {name3: 'field_name3'}
                 ],
                 data: jsonData
    });
    // create the Grid
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
               store: myStore,
               stateful: true,
               stateId: 'stateGrid',
               columns: [ {
                       text : 'field_name1',
                       sortable : false,
                       dataIndex: 'field_name1' // add fields you want to display
               }, ... ]               
               renderTo: 'table' // add other params as you want
    });
};
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, it does not help.. i have a store, but the json must be first loadet into the store, because without comboboxes ids, the result is = null :( I have to press the button and then the json to pass into the store, how?